# Need help vectorizing this code

Tags: c++, opencv, vectorization

I have an 8-bit image.  For each pixel, I need to work out its ordinal position in the current row.  For example, if the row is:

```
32 128 16 64,
```

then I need the result:

```
1 3 0 2,
```

since 32 is the 1st highest value in the row, 128 is 3rd highest, 16 is 0th highest and 64 is 2nd highest.

I need to repeat the above procedure for all rows of the image.  Here is the non-vectorized code:

```
for (int curr = 0; curr < new_height; ++curr)
{
    vector<pair<unsigned char, char> > ordered;
    for (char i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        unsigned char val = luma24.at<unsigned char>(curr, i);
        ordered.push_back(pair<unsigned char, char>(val, i));
    }
    sort(ordered.begin(), ordered.end(), cmpfun);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        signature.at<char>(curr, ordered[i].second) = i;
}
```

`luma24` is the 8-bit image I'm reading from, and it has `new_height` rows and 4 columns.  `signature` is a signed image of the same size (ignore the difference in sign for now, since its not relevant) -- it's where I'm storing the result. `cmpfun` is a trivial comparator function.

I tried to vectorize the above code and got this:

```
Mat ordinal;
luma24.convertTo(ordinal, CV_16UC1, 256, 0);
Mat sorted = ordinal.clone();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    ordinal(Range::all(), Range(i, i+1)) += i;
cv::sort(ordinal, sorted, CV_SORT_EVERY_ROW | CV_SORT_ASCENDING);
bitwise_and(sorted, Scalar(0x00ff), ordinal);
Mat ordinal8;
ordinal.convertTo(ordinal8, CV_8SC1, 1, 0);
ordinal8.copyTo(signature(Range::all(), Range(0, 4)));
```

I had to pack the 8-bit value and the 8-bit ordinal into a single 16-bit channel since OpenCV doesn't perform sort for multi-channel images.     This is almost what I need, but not quite.  For the example input, it gives me:

```
2 0 3 1
```

since the lowest value is in the 2nd column, next-lowest is in the 0th column, etc.  How do I go about converting this to the result I need without accessing each pixel individually?

Essentially, I need to somehow vectorize this:

```
uint8_t x[] = {2, 0, 3, 1};
uint8_t y[4];
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    y[x[i]] = i;
```

where `x` is the intermediate result my current vectorized code gives me and `y` is the result I want.

Can it be done?

Comment: Just for clarification (I don't have an answer yet) - What do you want to do if you have multiple pixels with the same value? Should they all be the same ordinal?

Comment: Off topic: What a coincidence, just the other day I was reading the [ffmpeg tutorial](https://github.com/mpenkov/ffmpeg-tutorial) source code you had mirrored on github. The url stopped working so I went to your profile in case you renamed it but I guess you removed it, and right now I recognized your avatar by chance.

Comment: In this form it's next to impossible. What constraints there are? e.g. is x[] always 4 element wide? should it be uint8_t instead?

Comment: @roger_rowland: no, the ordinal values must be unique, even if there are multiple pixels with the same value. @Jorge Israel Peña: somebody else is having a look after that at the moment.  Have a look at http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html for an updated link.  @ Aki Suihkonen: no, it won't always be four elements wide.  Yes, `uint8_t` is better -- I was just being lazy.

Comment: Don't you just need `cv:sortIdx()`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do the trick for you.  It doesn't require allocations or stacks or sorts, but does assume your range is 0-255 (e.g. uint8).  The bigger assumption: It will only be performant if you have wide rows.  If they're really 4 pixels wide, that i<256 is kinda ugly. There are ways to make that go away, but I'm assuming the 4 pixels is just an "e.g." for simplicity.

```
void processRow (int* rowpos, uint8_t* pixelsForRow, int w) {
   uint32_t i, pv, v=0, hist[256]={0};
   for (i=0; i<w; i++)      hist[pixelsForRow[i]]++;
   for (i=0; i<256; i++)    {pv=hist[i]; hist[i]=v; v+=pv;}
   for (i=0; i<w; i++)      rowpos[i] = hist[pixelsForRow[i]]++;
}
```

OK - so how does it work?
line 1 in this function declares and empties a histogram table.
line 2 computes a histogram.
line 3 turns it into a counted sort - and is why hist uses larger element size than uint8
line 4 applies the sorted position.
There are 2 tricks;  First, in line 3, the histograms are "shifted by 1 index" such the first value is always '0' not whatever it would, and the second value is what the first count would have been, and so on.
The second trick is the "++" in line 4 -- always ensures the ordinal value are unique.
Lets try it on your input:
[32  128  16  64]
line 2: [0...1....1....1...1...0] at indices [0, 16, 32, 64, 128, 255] respectively
line 3: [0...0....1....2...3...0] at indices [0, 16, 32, 64, 128, 255] respectively
line 4: [1, 3, 0, 2] ... looks right

Lets try it on slightly different input:
[32  128  16  32]
line 2: [0...1....2....0...1...0] at indices [0, 16, 32, 64, 128, 255] respectively
line 3: [0...0....1....3...3...0] at indices [0, 16, 32, 64, 128, 255] respectively
line 4: [1, 3, 0, 2] ... perfect

but I'm not quite sure if it meets your need for vectorization -- :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way I can think of is ,
For each row, create a binary search tree. While doing inorder traversal we can get the rank of each pixel.

Each element of the node is a structure

```
// Members of struct explained here.
// row_pos: stores position of that pixel in that row.
//     we populate this while creating binary search tree. 
//
// rank: stores its rank in that row. ()
//  while doing in-order traversal, we come to know rank of that pixel. At that point only, we update that pixel location with its rank.

typedef struct node
{
    int row_pos, rank; 
    node *left, *right;    // left and right nodes.
};
```

sequence of steps for every row would be:

a) O(w):  create a binary search tree by storing every pixel's position also in the node.

b) O(w): Start in-order traversal. For every node, fill the pixel location of that node with rank (start counting with first node as 0).